# How can I use is_page() inside a plugin?

Tags: wordpress

I want my plugin to register a script only in a certain page.

For example, inside my plugin file I want to write something like this:

```
if (is_page()) {
    $pageid_current = get_the_ID();
    $page_slug = get_post($pageid_current)->post_name;

    if ($page_slug == 'articles'){
        wp_register_script('myscript', '/someurl/main.js');
    }
}
```

But I get the error:

> is_page was called incorrectly. Conditional query tags do not work
>   before the query is run. Before then, they always return false. Please
>   see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was
>   added in version 3.1.)

How can I, inside of a plugin, register a script in a certain page?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`is_page()` only work within template files.

And to use it within plugin files, you need to use it with the combination of [`template_redirect`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect) action hook.

> This action hook executes just before WordPress determines which template page to load.

So following snippet would work:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'plugin_is_page' );

function plugin_is_page() {
    if ( is_page( 'articles' ) ) {
        wp_register_script( 'my-js-handler', '/someurl/main.js', [], '1.0.0', true );
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't working for me ... also by your logic how can it know what page it is to load in is_page() if it executes before it determines which template to load?

Also what do you think of this:
https://markjaquith.wordpress.com/2014/02/19/template_redirect-is-not-for-loading-templates/ ?

Comment: @MichaelPaccione `template_include` fits best for template inclusion i.e. loading a different template than what's decided by core template hierarchy. In the OP case above, only script is required to enqueued, thus I used `template_redirect` because this is the first hook that is available to determine which template page is going to be loaded.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `is_page()` after template redirect so you need to add in the hook like this :

```
add_action('template_redirect','your_function');
function your_function(){
 if ( is_page('test') ) {
  // do you thing.
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must **register** your script as if you want it to work everywhere.
You can de-register it after the job is done, like this:

```
function deregister_my_script() {
    if (!is_page('page-d-exemple') ) {
        wp_deregister_script( 'custom-script-1' );
    }
}
add_action('wp_print_scripts', 'deregister_my_script', 100 );
```

Comment: It's OK, if you have to modify my question/comment/answer. But, you forgot the main point : this is done to make Ajax works.