# How to make wordpress function working only on single & NOT for pages

Tags: php, wordpress, function, posts

I'm struggling with one thing. I've got such wordpress function:

```
   function wpq_insert_attachment_data($data, $postarr){
if (!is_single() ) {
    $posttitle = get_the_title( $postarr['post_parent'] );
    $data['post_title'] = $posttitle;
    $data['post_name'] = $posttitle;    
    return $data;        
}}  

add_filter( 'wp_insert_attachment_data', 'wpq_insert_attachment_data', 10, 2 );
```

It works superb but it covers all single/custom post type/pages etc. Is there any way to EXCLUDE pages from that function? I've tried sorting it out with `is_single()` yet without success.

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22070223/how-can-i-use-is-page-inside-a-plugin

than add your hook inside the redirect function

Comment: @Bart - it doesn't work. It still execute for ALL type of elements: posts/pages.. take a look on updated code.

Comment: can you paste your new code?

Comment: Added (edited initial post).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use is_singular in your statement to target specific post types.

Can also do an array to include or exclude.

```
If  (! is_singular()) ..... or.....
 (! is_singular(array('page','food',foo')))
```

Then it will only run on the singles for whichever post type you're targeting.

Answer (score 1):

Load the function only on specific page, add your page id in `is_page(id_here)` :

```
 function wpq_insert_attachment_data($data, $postarr){
     if ( is_page(page_id)){
       $posttitle = get_the_title( $postarr['post_parent'] );
        $data['post_title'] = $posttitle;
        $data['post_name'] = $posttitle;    
        return $data;  
    }
 }

 add_filter( 'wp_insert_attachment_data', 'wpq_insert_attachment_data', 10, 2 );
```

you can also add your page slug instead of id like :

```
if ( is_page('slug'))
```

Or exclude page(s)

```
if ( !is_page('slug'))

if ( !is_page(array('slug-1', 'slug-2') )
```

Comment: But pages are in fact the element which I want to exclude (so I want to execute function everywhere except pages)

Comment: then try using `!is_page()`

Comment: why dont you put page ids & restrict it if you dont have so many pages like `if ( !is_page(page_id) ||  !is_page(page_id) )`

Comment: this doesn't work. I don't know why by function applies to everything. Even if im strictly declare: is_page(2)

Comment: Not working because there's a missing closing bracket before the add_filter() function.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you just need to tweak your conditional statement:

`if (!is_single() ) {`

Should become:

`if (!is_page() ) {`

Comment: Not working. Ive found out on other forum thread that in functions.php for my purposes is_page etc will not work and i should use get_post_type( $postarr['post_parent'] ). But still It tells me nothing:(