# Disable Jetpack Carousel on specific pages in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, carousel, jetpack

I'm trying to disable Jetpack Carousel on a specific post ID using the following code in my functions.php

```
function djcoh_disable_carousel( $value ) {

    wp_reset_query();
    if ( is_page( 614 ) ) {
        $value = true; // true to disable Carousel
    }
    // Return original or changed value
    return $value;

}

add_filter( 'jp_carousel_maybe_disable', 'djcoh_disable_carousel' );
```

Here's the reference for jp_carousel_maybe_disable on [GitHub](https://github.com/Automattic/jetpack/blob/5.8/modules/carousel/jetpack-carousel.php/#L98)

It seems that I'm unable to use is_page() within functions.php - though I thought I'd be able to by using wp_reset_query() as mentioned in the [codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/#notes)

What am I missing?!

Comment: Why do you think you are unable to use is_page ? How have you isolated it as being this? Have you tried your code without the if clause to see if the code actually disable the carousel?

Comment: I've verified that it disables the carousel on all pages without the if clause. This other SO answer lead me to believe that I can't use is_page() in functions.php https://stackoverflow.com/a/22070503/3650556

Comment: also, why are your using `wp_reset_query();`? its need to use after `query_posts`,

Comment: I got that from here https://premium.wpmudev.org/forums/topic/how-to-disable-jetpack-carousel-on-one-page and also saw it referenced on the WP codex for is_page()

Comment: As @SamvelAleqsanyan says reset is usually used after a custom query to kick everything back to the loop query.

Comment: This code is intended for use as a simple plugin, have you tried it as such, just to make sure it works as expected? If, so we can then narrow this down to the "is_page" function.

Comment: Yes. Tried it 'As is' as a plugin instead of in functions.php using the original is_front_page() - it did not disable the carousel on the front page.

Comment: Also, tried it as a plugin but using is_page() - same deal

Comment: Ever figure this out?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I ended up working around it though by using the WP function is_page() to conditionally add the following jQuery to the page where I needed to disable the carousel: `jQuery('.gallery-item').on('click', function(e) {e.stopPropagation();});`

Comment: @MarkAnderson Did my answer or one of the other help you? If so please mark the appropriate answer as the accepted solution. Or, post an update and we'll try to help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The code you have is from a tutorial which is intended for running as a simple plugin. The reason your code doesn't currently work is because you are using it in the functions.php.

In it's current form your function is called as soon as it is read as part of the functions.php file. This is usually some time before the page is formed, and so you can't grab the page id with `is_page{}`.

Instead you should query the page and get it's id as follows:

```
function djcoh_disable_carousel( $value ) {

//get the global
global $post
echo "TEST PAGE ID: ".$post->ID;
//wp_reset_query();
if ( $post->ID == 614 ) {
    $value = true; // true to disable Carousel
}

wp_reset_query();
// Return original or changed value
return $value;

}

add_filter( 'jp_carousel_maybe_disable', 'djcoh_disable_carousel' );
```

if that doesn't work try this:

```
function djcoh_disable_carousel( $value ) {

//get the global
global $wp_query;
$post_ID = $wp_query->post->ID;
echo "TEST PAGE ID: ". $post_ID;
//wp_reset_query();
if ( $post_ID == 614 ) {
    $value = true; // true to disable Carousel
}

wp_reset_query();
// Return original or changed value
return $value;

}

add_filter( 'jp_carousel_maybe_disable', 'djcoh_disable_carousel' );
```

If none of the above work then your script is being called far too early in the process to grab the page id. So, the easiest option would be to simply place this script in it's own .php file and then upload that to the plugins root folder. Then activate it from the plugins menu.

The final option would be to create this as a filter or script and add the function call in the actual page template.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Still same issue though - it works on all pages without the if clause - but as soon as I add `if ( $post->ID == 614 )` or `is_page` it stops working

Comment: Ok, try my updated code. If it doesn't work are you seeing the page ID output via the echo?

Comment: Still not working. It does echo out "TEST PAGE ID: " but not the page id

Comment: Same! added a semicolon to `global $post;` but still not echoing the page id

Comment: Just added another 2 final options.

Comment: Still no-go, but thanks Phill. I don't quite follow the 'final option' - could you elaborate on that?

Comment: Which, the simple plugin (easiest option by far) or adding the function to your page template?

Comment: Both. I tried the simple plugin and tried adding the function directly to the page.php template (where I tried adding the function before, within, and after the main while loop).

Comment: Ok, so take your original code, place it in a file named mycarouselfix.php. Then add '<?php' then your code and finally '?>' now upload it to your plugins root eg 'wp-content' > 'plugins'. Now activate the plugin and it should work.

Comment: Did anyone ever verify that this works? I can't get it to work. I tried 1. adding it in my site-specific plugin, 2. adding to functions.php, 3. adding as a separate plugin. 4. I can get the function to fire (and detect the front page) if I use a different filter like `wp`, but that doesn't disable carousel. 5. I tried adding the filter in a few different spots in my page templates, but no good. 6. I tried applying the filter with the function always returning true, and it disables the jetpack carousel. All of the pieces are there, but  this hook seems to fire before WP knows what page it's on.

Answer (score 1):

I managed this by using REQUEST_URI within a plugin file:

```
<?php

// No direct access
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit;

if ( $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] === '/PAGE-SLUG/' ) {
    add_filter( 'jp_carousel_maybe_disable', '__return_true' );
}
```

Change PAGE-SLUG for your slug and you are all set.

You can find info on REQUEST_URI in [PHP's manuals](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php):

> 'REQUEST_URI'
>       The URI which was given in order to access this page; for instance, '/index.html'.

Answer (score 0):

It seems simplest to conditionally dequeue the Jetpack carousel script and stylesheet. The conditionals that you would typically use to control output would be available at the point in the request when the wp_footer action fires.

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', function() {
    if ( is_page( $page ) ) {
        wp_dequeue_script( 'jetpack-carousel' );
        wp_dequeue_style( 'jetpack-carousel' );
    }
}
```

Be certain to modify the [is_page](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/) function to include the *$page* parameter or the condition will match all pages. [Place the code in your theme's functions.php](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/theme-functions/) file and the Jetpack carousel should be disabled.